# Spring Boot Restcontroller JSON Response doesnt include any property names but only values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get familiar with  Java and Spring Boot and I have managed to set up a service and a controller as I needed but there is one minor issue I can not seem to solve.

The Get Mapping should return a List of Classes from a 3rd party library, which it does. The Issue is that it is not including the property names in the JSON response.

```
    @GetMapping("/{symbol}/{timeframe}")
public List<Candlestick> getOHLCV(@PathVariable("symbol") String symbol,
        @PathVariable("timeframe") String timeframe) {

    return service.getOHLCV(symbol, IntervalConverter.fromString(timeframe));
}
```

The Candlestick Class holds properties like open, high,low,close but these property names are all missing in the response. Why is that the case and how to solve that?

I get a response array like this:

[[1675190700000,"23143.08000000","23179.36000000","23141.26000000","23178.22000000","766.15847000",1675190999999,"17746710.34454660",22165,"453.83717000","10512390.22459520"]]

Comment: yes, a list in JSON looks like an array. does your Candlestick class implement a toString() function? what do you see if you print out the response of the service method call?

Comment: Yes it should be an array but an array of JSON objects including their properties like close:number, high:number etc.

When I system.out.println the service response inside the controller it is logged correctly including all properties

139490.04905910], Candlestick[openTime=1675209000000,open=23134.49000000,high=23157.64000000,low=23122.79000000,close=23150.110000

Comment: Can you share code for Candlestick class?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @JsonProperty on property name

```
public class Candlestick {
   @JsonProperty("open")
   private String open;

   @JsonProperty("high")
   private String high;

   @JsonProperty("low")
   private String low;

   @JsonProperty("close")
   private String close;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I can not edit the Candlestick class, it comes from a 3rd party maven repo and my editor won't let me edit it.

Comment: it says can not edit in read-only mode. But also, if I would edit the 3rd party module files and deploy the app to a remote server, wouldnt it just download the dependencies default state a gain and the project fails to work anyway?